# How to print samba share options?

Tags: linux, windows, debian, samba, cifs

Considering a standalone samba server. Looks like the number of share options goes over a couple of hundreds, like presented in https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/appc.pdf.

The options set on the glogal section are applied to the shares also, if not explictly set for the share. Even not specifying them, on global or directly on the share, default settings are assumed for each option, I guess.

Is there a way to print all current settings (share options) for a specific share?